# Any reason to use Azure Web Apps instead of Azure Web Apps for Containers?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-app-for-containers

I'm pretty new to Azure, so for the sake of learning, I have deployed Node.js applications in Azure both as Docker containers and Azure web apps on Linux. Since Azure web apps are containers anyway, is there any good reason why I should use them instead of my own containers, which I have better control over?

One problem I stumbled upon was that you have to take quite a few things into account with the preconfigured containers in Azure web apps, some of that described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps). If I instead use my own Docker containers, I don't have to take the extra steps that are sometimes required to get your Node.js application with its dependencies up and running as an Azure web app.

Am I missing something, or is it as it now seems to me, less work to deploy my apps in Azure as Docker containers?

Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but I think there is a difference in the security updates of application SW (e.g. NodeJs). When you use a custom docker image you might be responsible for keeping the containers up to date.

Comment: Good point! So it seems to be tradeoff question: spend time learning the Azure web app container setup and configuration specifics, or spend time keeping your own container up to date.